# Check if all attributes exist as dict keys in one (and only one) index of nested tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following Python tuple:

```
my_tuple = ( "key1", ("nested_key1", "nested_key2"), "key3")
```

I am required to test if a dict contains either `"key1"`, all elements in `("nested_key1", "nested_key2")`, or `"key3"`.  If there is a match for all elements at any of the root tuple's indexs, then the algorithm should only evaluate as `True` if there are NO other matches in other indexes.  If there are additional keys not specified in the tuple, these can be disregarded for matching purposes.

Meaning that...

*These should return True:*

```
matching_dict_root = {"key1": 1}
matching_dict_nested = {"nested_key1": 2, "nested_key2": 3}
unspecified_keys_are_allowed = {"key1": 1, "99problems": 99}
```

*These should be False:*

```
too_many = {"key1": 1, "nested_key1": 1, "nested_key2": 2}
also_wrong = {"key1": 1, "nested_key2": 1}
```

Can assume (for  my current case, but general solutions are most welcome):

- only 1 nested level
- all individual attributes (at all depths) are globally unique

Python-3.6 please, Python-2.7 also helpful, but not required.  If possible (I presume it is, and that I'll kick myself), std. lib. only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been driving me nuts, but here it is...

To get a flattened list of the tuple, we use this helper function from [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists):

```
def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten(el)
        else:
            yield el
```

This will allow for testing invalid intersections using `frozenset.isdisjoint()` against a sublist of the flattened list.

The final solution, after expanding @DanD.'s helpful solution, is therefore:

```
def all_attributes_exist_with_null_intersection(iterable, d):
    return sum((i in d if not isinstance(i, tuple) else (all(sub_i in d for sub_i in i)))
               and frozenset(d.keys()).isdisjoint(flatten([x for x in i if x != i]))
               for i in iterable) == 1
```

**Tests:**

```
sample_tuple = ("key1", ("nested_key1", "nested_key2"), "key3")

true_tests = [
    {"key1": 1},
    {"nested_key1": 2, "nested_key2": 3},
    {"key1": 1, "99problems": 99}
]

false_tests = [
    {"key1": 1, "nested_key1": 1, "nested_key2": 2},
    {"key1": 1, "nested_key2": 1}
]

trues = [all_attributes_exist_with_null_intersection(sample_tuple, d) for d in true_tests]
falses = [all_attributes_exist_with_null_intersection(sample_tuple, d) for d in false_tests]

print("Trues:\n{trues}\n\nFalses:\n{falses}".format(
    trues=trues,
    falses=falses
)
```

**Output:**

```
Trues:
[True, True, True]

Falses:
[False, False]
```

**Caveats:**

- Python 3.3 required for `yield from` in helper function

Answer (score 1):

So like:

```
sum( keys in D if not isinstance(keys, tuple) 
               else all( key in D for key in keys )
     for keys in my_tuple ) == 1
```

The reason for `sum( ) == 1` rather than `any( )` is:

> only evaluate as True if there are NO other matches in other indexes

Which means that there should only be one index in `my_tuple` that is `True` the rest must be `False`.

Comment: This gives incorrect output for `{"key1", "nested_key2"}`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, correct, that's the missing case in this solution.  I updated the question to correct the derpy dicts that I wrote.

Comment: The description of the problem states that example would be True.

Comment: @DanD., please see `{"key1": 1, "nested_key2": 1}`.  I've noted that this is should return `False`.